# Change the active selection of website by VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to change the limit of products showing in the page from '15' to 'all' by VBA code through Excel module.

```
<fieldset class="results-per-page">
 <span> 
    <label>Results per page</label>
    <a href="#15" id="15" class="active">15</a>
    <a href="#30" id="30" >30</a>
    <a href="#all" id="all">View All</a>
 </span>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks ,I found the solution,

here is the code -

```
      If IE.Document.Links.Length > 0 Then

For i = 1 To 600
        If IE.Document.Links(i) = "http://www.xyz.com/computer/all-products#all" Then
           IE.Document.Links(i).Click
        End If
Next i

       End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not directly navigate to that? For example `ie.navigate sURL & "#all"`? Where sURL is the web address of the above page...

See this example

```
Sub sample()
    Dim ie As Object
    Dim sURL As String

    '~~> Change this to the relevant URL
    sURL = "D:\Users\SidzPc\Desktop\test.htm"

    Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
    ie.Visible = True

    ie.navigate sURL & "#all"
End Sub
```

**ScreenShot**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply,but that site is using javascript therefore URL is not changing and not accepting any parameter.

Comment: I think , this is the javascript code executed on selection change.<script type="text/javascript">
 var login_status = ""
 var product_names = ["XYZ","ABC"];
 var product_ids = ["1","1"];
 var product_prices = ["1899.99","1499.99"];
 var product_categories= ["PCs","PCs"];
 var product_subcategories = ["Laptops","Laptops"];
 if (isLogin()) {
 login_status = "logged in";
 else {login_status = "logged out";}

Comment: var utag_data = {page_type : "Category Filter",page_name : "PCs-Category Filter",site_language : "en",loggedin_status : login_status,division : "PCs",responsive_design_mode : "t", page_breadcrumb : "Shop > PCs > All PCs",page_channel : "product",
  product_id : product_ids,
  product_price : product_prices,
  product_name : product_names,
  product_category :product_categories,
  product_subcategory : product_subcategories, 
  site_search_results : "29",
  results_per_page: "15" 
 };

Comment: May I see the website URL?

Comment: I can't share on the portal  because of some security issue but I will forward you on your personnel email.

Comment: Hi Siddharth, your emailid ?

Comment: And I can't share the email id on a public site :P